# Android - detect shake direction

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, gesturedetector, sensormanager

I saw lots of examples of how to detect ***shaking*** of an **Android** device, but didn't get how to detect the direction (I want it to detect *shake* to the ***left/right***). All the examples I've encountered have some deprecated methods and were actual several years ago.

Could you please provide an **up-to-date** example?